# OpenSSL Error "PHP OpenSSL extension not working"

Tags: typo3

When I visit the **System environment** section in the Install tool, TYPO3 will print:

> PHP OpenSSL extension not working

But it won't tell me what the actual problem is. How can I find out the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPO3 executes [`openssl_pkey_new()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php) and only checks the return value, ignoring any actual errors.

To find out what the problem is, just execute the function yourself.

```
echo '<?php openssl_pkey_new(); ?>' | php 2>&1
```

Which might print an error like:

> PHP Warning:  openssl_pkey_new(): Error loading request_extensions_section section v3_req of /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf in - on line 1

Which would indicate a problem with your OpenSSL configuration.

Comment: Great hint. To ensure that the Web version of PHP is called, put the call of `openssl_pkey_new()` in a PHP file and load it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition as you might need to recompile your php installation.
I'm literally compiling my php 7.1.8 on a Mac Sierra with --with-openssl flag right now. I have come across with missing evp.h error during configuration. The way I solved this is to locate the evp.h, which is likely installed in several places. Take most relevant where openssl is installed, likely in /usr/local and use this as the optional directory:

```
./configure --with-open=/usr/local
```

I hope this helps.